# Graphql message thread design

Tags: schema, graphql

I’m creating a message thread schema, where users join the message thread, and fetch the messages for this particular thread.

Front end: Each message should show a little avatar & name
This means that I need to fetch the user who sent the message for every single message (this is the current implementation - running a db query to get the user for every single message)

A solution for this was to grab the users at the thread level. This would mean I’d have to match the `message.user_id` with the `thread.thread_users['user_id']`. Would it be weird if I did this on the front-end? I feel like I should be attaching the user for that particular message on the backend?

Is there a way I could pass down my `thread.thread_users` array into my `messages` connection?

Here is the current query I have:

```
thread(input...) {
  id
  // THIS HOLDS THE USERS WHO ARE IN THIS THREAD
  threadUsers {
    name
    firstName
    avatar {
      original
      thumbnail
      medium
    }
  }
  lastReadMessageId
  messages {
    edges {
          cursor
          node {
            from {
              firstName
              lastName
            }
            messageContent
          }
    }
  }
}
```

I guess the question is:

Is it possible to grab the `thread_users` array from inside the Message type? So I can then match the `thread_user` to the `message.user_id`

OR whether I should be matching the `thread_users` to the `message.from_id` on the front-end?

The database looks like this:

thread:

- id
- created_at
- owner_id

messages:

- from_id (the user who sent the message)
- messageContent (the message content)

thread_users: (simply there to record what users are in which threads)

- thread_id
- user_id

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was letting the front-end handle this. I could've potentially used Dataloader with Graphql but there was no need.